# RePost (bounce) received datas the same using curl

Tags: php, curl, post, bounce

Does anyone knows How to bounce (RePost, exactly the same way) an array (datas) previously posted to my page ?

Here is how i do by now, guess it's not the best way :

**Received datas**

```
$_datas = $_REQUEST;
```

**and how i rePost ?**

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/new_script.php');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_datas);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Anyone has an idea ? Please ;)

Comment: Why do you use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: Sometime datas comes in $_GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **re-post** data which comes in `GET` and `POST`, your code almost complete. Just need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

So, code will be like this

```
$_datas = $_REQUEST;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/new_script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_datas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result     = curl_exec($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```